# Python & pymssql: get message returned from Database after command is executed?

Tags: python, pymssql

Is there a way to access the return message after a SQL query is executed using `pymsql`?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table;")
cursor.get_return_message?
```

Comment: What kind of message do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are at least four you can use in this fashion:

```
 rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

 print("Total # of rows: " + str(rows.rowcount))

 for row in rows:
     print("Looping over row #" + str(rows.rownumber))

     if(rows.rowcount == rows.rownumber):
         print("Yay, we're done.')
```

There's also Cursor.connection. More information here:

http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html

Scroll down to Cursor object properties (misspelled Cusor in the docs). Good luck!